# Laravel 4 Undefined variable: file_destination issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Once I post the form with and image upload the first time it works. But when I do it again it gives me this error,

```
Undefined variable: file_destination
```

Here is all of my code that uses file_destination:

```
if(isset($_FILES['img'])) {
            $file = $_FILES['img'];

            // File properties
            $file_name = $file['name'];
            $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
            $file_size = $file['size'];
            $file_error = $file['error'];

            // Work out the file extension
            $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
            $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

            $allowed = array('png', 'jgp', 'jpeg', 'gif');

            if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) {
                if($file_error === 0) {
                    if($file_size <= 180000000) {

                        $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.'  . $file_ext;
                        $file_destination = 'img/content-imgs/' . $file_name_new;

                        if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)) {
                            echo '<img src="' .$file_destination. '">';
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }   

        $title  = Input::get('title');
        $slug   = Input::get('slug');
        $body   = Markdown::parse(Input::get('body'));
        $draft  = Input::get('draft');
        $created_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $updated_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $post = DB::table('posts')
            ->insert(array(
                'title' => $title,
                'slug' => $slug,
                'body' => $body,
                'img' => $file_destination,
                'draft' => $draft,
                'created_at' => $created_at,
                'updated_at' => $updated_at
        ));
```

Can someone please help me understand why I'm getting this error.

Comment: It's obvious. The `$file_destination` is undefined. `if` code earlier doesn't happen?

Comment: Which line is it? Please mark it somehow in the code.

Comment: if file size is `$file_size <= 180000000` then only the `$file_destination` is define , what if the `$file_size < 180000000` then there is no variable `$file_size` in `'img' => $file_destination,` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ali Gajani wrote in the comments. `$file_destination` is undefined when the first if

```
if(isset($_FILES['img'])) {
```

is false. So the whole code inside the if statement won't be executed. Especially the line where `$file_destination` gets declared.

```
$file_destination = 'img/content-imgs/' . $file_name_new;
```

The solution is simple. Just declare `$file_destination` before the if statement so it will be defined no matter what.

```
$file_destination = null;

if(isset($_FILES['img'])){
    // ...
    $file_destination = 'img/content-imgs/' . $file_name_new;
    // ...
}

// now $file_destination either is null or contains the path
```

I chose `null` as default value. You could also use an empty string or something else. Only make sure your variables are defined.